# Remove similar Rectangles from a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List containing a few thousand rectangles. I'm trying to reduce the size of the list by removing items whose location is within x pixels of other items.

So far, my best attempt has been:

```
list = list.GroupBy(x => x.Location).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

but this only removes exact matches. I'd love to remove all that are reasonably similar. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please the whole Location class properties, so it could be easy to understand question

Comment: I suggest not using Linq but some simple for-loop in which you examine each item in the list and compare their location with the preceding items (or following items; your choice). If another item is found with a "similar location" remove the currently examined item (or the other item; again, your choice) from the list. Not sure what you where going after in your extensive research, but to implement this suggestion here just needs some basic knowledge of how to do for-loops and how to work with lists...

Comment: I'd love to help answer this, but we need to know what the Location object has in it (whether it's just an x/y, a lat/long, or something else) to give a relevant answer.

Comment: Indeed. Location is a point (x,y). Thanks!

Comment: So `list` is a `List<Point>`? Please edit your question to add more detail.

Comment: What should happen if every rectangle is close enough to the next so they all (could) form one group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying (as well as I can) to follow @EricLippert's sage advice, and think about the data structures first.

WLOG, assume `Location` contains a `Windows.System.Point`. We create a couple of handy extensions to help us later:

```
public static class PointExt {
    public static double Distance(this Point p1, Point p2) => (p1-p2).Length;
    public static Point PointZero = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Now we can define our `Rectangle` type (simplified for this problem):

```
public class Rectangle {
    public string Site;
    public Point Loc;

    public Rectangle() { }

    public Rectangle(string site, Point loc) {
        Site = site;
        Loc = loc;
    }
}
```

NOTE: `Site` is just to help in testing.

Now what we want to create are groups of `Rectangle`s that are all close to each other. I choose to define close as meaning within 5 units of the center of the (`Location`s of the) group, found by averaging the current group's members.

So we can create a `RectangleGroup` class to help us with this definition:

```
public class RectangleGroup : IEnumerable<Rectangle> {
    List<Rectangle> members;
    Point center;

    public RectangleGroup() {
        members = new List<Rectangle>();
    }

    public RectangleGroup Add(Rectangle r) {
        members.Add(r);
        center = new Point(members.Average(m => m.Loc.X), members.Average(m => m.Loc.Y));
        return this;
    }

    public bool BelongsToGroup(Rectangle r) => center.Distance(r.Loc) <= 5;

    public Rectangle Middle() => members.OrderBy(m => m.Loc.Distance(center)).First();

    public IEnumerator<Rectangle> GetEnumerator() => members.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

I implemented `IEnumerable` on the group to make it possible to use LINQ with a `RectangleGroup`.

Using our tools in `RectangleGroup`, we can create a `RectangleGroups` class which manages a collection of `RectangleGroup`s similar to `Lookup`. This makes me think a (very) generic version of `GroupBy` could be created that delegates the group membership to a type could be useful, and would make this class unecessary.

```
public class RectangleGroups : IEnumerable<RectangleGroup> {
    List<RectangleGroup> groups;
    public RectangleGroups() {
        init();
    }

    public RectangleGroups(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rs) {
        init();

        foreach (var r in rs.OrderBy(r => r.Loc.Distance(PointExt.PointZero)))
            Add(r);
    }

    private void init() {
        groups = new List<RectangleGroup>();
    }

    public void Add(Rectangle r) {
        var found = false;
        foreach (var g in groups) {
            found = g.BelongsToGroup(r);
            if (found) {
                g.Add(r);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            groups.Add(new LocationGroup().Add(r));
    }

    public IEnumerator<LocationGroup> GetEnumerator() => groups.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

With these classes available, reducing the `List<Rectangle>` to just each `Rectangle` nearest the center of each group is trivial:

```
var ans = new RectangleGroups(list).Select(lg => lg.Middle());
```

Comment: Thanks @NetMage for such an in-depth answer. This information proved to be very useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track.  Think about how you're generating keys for the group by.  Maybe generate keys based on close-ness rather than exact match.

```
list = list.GroupBy(x => ApproximateLocation(x.Location)).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();


public Location ApproximateLocation(Location original)
{
  int precision = 5;
  Location result = new Location{
    X = (original.X / precision) * precision;
    Y = (original.Y / precision) * precision;

  };
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work too well when two objects are one pixel apart on opposite sides of two adjacent approximation bounding boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom comparison function and use it in the GroupBy clause.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

list.GroupBy(x => x.Location, new CustomComparer())...

public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<LocationType>
{
    public bool Equals(LocationType A, LocationType B)
    {
        //return true if A is close enough to B
    }
}
```

This article goes into great detail: https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/06/20/grouping-elements-in-linq-net-using-groupby-and-an-equalitycomparer/

Comment: I don't see how that would help since `GroupBy` groups on the properties discernible from a single member.

Comment: This method compares all the elements to each other by the selected key (x.Location in this example) using the IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals(T, T) method.

Comment: I don't believe it actually compares every element. Imagine you have 3 locations, A, B and C. A->B is close, A->C is close, B->C is too far - what will `GroupBy` do?

Comment: Also consider that `GroupBy` uses `GetHashCode` to determine groups which is passed only one `LocationType` object at a time - how would you define that?

Comment: I tested and setting `GetHashCode(LocationType A) => 1;` works around that issue, but does not solve the other.